Convergence in distribution of partial sums of indepent discrete random variables
$\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a family of independent random variables such that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n} = 1\right) =
\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}\quad \mbox{and}\quad
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n} = -n^{2}\right) =
\frac{2}{n^{2} + 1}
$$
$$
\mbox{Let}\ S_{n} = X_{1} + \cdots + X_{n}
$$

The Three-Series Theorem tells me that $S_{n}$ does not converge almost surely.
But what about convergence in distribution or probability ?.

Intuitively I want to say it doesn't, but I don't know how to go about proving it.
Two things I've observed:

$X_{n}$ converges to $X \equiv 1$ in distribution ( and probability ).
$\mathbb{E}X_{n} = -1,\ \forall\ n;\quad$ hence $\quad\mathbb{E}S_{n} = -n \to -\infty$.

Can these facts be used to discuss convergence in distribution ?.

This might help

By Borel-Cantelli Lemma, only finitely many of the events $A_n:=\{X_n=-n^2\}$ will occur (as $\sum_n \mathbb P(A_n)<\infty$). Hence for all large enough $n$ we have $X_n=1$. Therefore, $S_n/n\to 1$ a.s.
